# asp.net charting

Tags: asp.net, charts, graph

I've never really done any charting or graphing in asp.net, but my current project is going to need some fairly extensive charting, in particular graphs that can be updated dynamicaly by the user, by changing start dates, criteria etc. I'm looking for some suggestions on the best charting tool for doing this.

I'd prefer a free tool, but may have some budget for a paid one. Will be using asp.net MVC written in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want the [ASP.NET Charting Control](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx). I have used it and I must say its excellent. Minimum effort/coding to create very rich and professional charts.

Comment: +1.  Good answer.  Quicker than me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's the [Asp.Net Chart Control from Microsoft](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx) that's free...

For non free charts, there's [Dundas Charts](http://www.dundas.com/).  I haven't used them personally, but they have a lot more to choose from, and they've been around for a while.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the [Microsoft Chart Controls](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en). They have a set of both asp.net and winforms controls for a wide range of chart types.

(You might find the [visual studio addin](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=1D69CE13-E1E5-4315-825C-F14D33A303E9&displaylang=en) helpful if you use these controls)

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest looking at [FusionCharts Free](http://www.fusioncharts.com/free) as a very easy to use charting component for ASP.NET. Or you could also consider [FusionCharts v3](http://www.fusioncharts.com) which has even more features.